# drop down menu not centered

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

I have a simple drop down menu, but no matter what, i cant get it to center on the page. I've tried so many things, and i have already searched other questions, cant get it to work.

Here is my html/php:

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li>Géneros
    <ul>
      <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `categorias` where 1";

        $result = mysqli_query ($ligacao, $query);

            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
                $categoria= $row['cod_categoria'];

                echo "<li><a href='artigos.php?catid=$categoria'>" . $row['nome_categoria'] . "</a></li>";

            }
        ?>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            echo "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<li><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='registo.php'>Registar</a></li>";
        }
        ?>
</ul>
```

And here is the css:

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
ul li ul li { 
  background: #555; 
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Everything is correct, righr? But the menu still appears on the left side of the page, i dont know why. After the menu i got a wrapper div, that have this css:

```
.wrapper {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
```

Maybe its this that its causing the menu to not center? I dont know... Can someone try to help me?

This is the only extra css i got:

```
body{
    background:url('symphony.png');
    color:#888;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font: 72.5% 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
.wrapper {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   text-align:center;
}
.artigo {
   background:#CCC;
   text-align:center;
    width:30%;
    height:60%;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}
img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at code that you provide and see that menu is centered:
http://jsfiddle.net/kc1bfn9z/

```
.other-css
```

May be some other css rules replace these css rules?

Comment: edited the question with the only other css i have on the page.